# VB.NET combobox displays System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: vb.net, dataset, dataadapter

I used this code:

```
 myCommand = New SqlComman("SELECT RackName FROM tblRack", myConnection)
 myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
 myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblRack")
 cboRack.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
```

then in the combobox i got the display "System.Data.DataRowView". Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt set the datavaluefield and datatextfield.

cboRack.datavaluefield = "RackName" 'Youre not using IDs ?
cboRack.datatextfield = "RackName"

Comment: but, once i used it in another form, it works. However, can u guid me this?